# spread spectrum communication and timing recovery

Tags: digital-communications

I use a DBPSK modulation. Each modulation symbol is spread by a signal $c_i(t)$ which is different for each DBPSK symbol. The transmitted signal is given by: $s(t)=\sum_{i=1}^{N_s}d_ic_i(t-iT_s)$ where $N_s$ is the number of DBPSK symbols and $T_s$ is the symbol time.

My question: At reception, how to do the timing recovery for the despreading? I thought about a sliding window but you have to know the length of the window which depends on the timing recovery.

Comment: Why does the length of the window depend on timing recovery? In a typical communication system, the symbol rate is known and fixed. Only the start time is unknown, that's why you use a sliding window correlator (with a fixed window length).